# Export image component in indd file

Tags: adobe-indesign

When I open the indd file using indesign, however, the image is very burry, but in fact the image is of high resolution (2048*1536). How should I export the blurry image component (e.g., the woman is a image component, and you can see there is a rectangle highlighted to woman) to a high resolution jpg file?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

If the image has sufficient effective PPI (for example 300ppi), then the exported image should be in "high resolution". In this case, your image can be printed up to 5.12 inches wide (1536/300) with satisfactory result, unless the actual printed area is cropped from the source, leading to reduced effective PPI. (You can enable effective PPI information going to `Links panel` -> `quick menu`  -> `panel options`)

Another more possible cause is that the linked file is somehow moved to a different folder, hence breaking the link. In this case, you will see errors in the preflight panel.

A third, but unlikely reason, is that the `Display Performance` is set to `typical` but not `high quality`.